# RestKit in a Workspace

Tags: ios, rest, static-libraries, restkit

I have a workspace set up in Xcode. It contains a number of static library projects that I link to in my main project.

The process of linking to these projects is much longer than it should be. But the key for me in getting this to work was removing the -ObjC linker flag from my build settings. This kept me from getting duplicate files when I used a library in more than one place.

But this gave me a problem when trying to include RestKit in my project, because the documentation says that the -ObjC linker flag is necessary, which I have found to be the case.

Is there a way of including RestKit in a workspace like this and linking to it like any other static library? Without having to use the -ObjC linker flag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to target your app for IOS 5 and above then you can try using the built-in NSURLConnection along with NSJSONSerialization class (If you return JSON response) for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried NSJSONSerialization and it is very useful. But if I can use RestKit then I will, as it also provides object mapping options and integration with Core Data.

Comment: Great, also instead of adding RestKit source you can also try creating a universal lib using the lipo(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) command and include the reskit.a along with header files to your project. In this way, you dont need to specify a -ObjC flag.